# Get last selected node

Tags: javascript

I get the first selected node like this:

```
var userSelection = window.getSelection();
var selected_element = userSelection.anchorNode;
```

But I haven't been able to find something like userSelection.endNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`focusNode` is the end of a selection. `anchorNode` is the beginning of a selection. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/focusNode).